# React JS - Can't resolve './react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Currently I'm doing a React JS course but it seems a bit outdated with some things. Currently I'm trying to implement the React Router within my code. I'm getting the error:

**ERROR in ./src/App.js 7:0-51**

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './react-router-dom'**

Although when I checked my package.json and also the route of the dir under the node modules, it's there. I tried also to use a different version from the react-router-dom in order to make it work, I tried with other computers as well but it is not.

I tried to uninstall npm modules and reinstall them again.

Other options I've tried:

npm i react-router-dom
npm install react-router-dom@5.3.4 and 4.2.2

I'm addding some screenshots about where is it called, node modules and relevant info.

[image: App.js]

[image: MainComponent.js]

[image: Node Module]

[image: Error]

Here you have my JSON package file dependencies info:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "node-modules": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-popper": "^2.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

Comment: You are trying to import something from `"./react-router-dom"` instead of `"react-router-dom"`. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo".

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also note that code should never be presented as images.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese I'm trying to use the react-router-dom for routing with a single page app. Thanks for your reply and if you need more detail let me know.

Comment: @JobV just remove the `./` and instead use `from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 1):

When you add `./`, you're telling React to look inside a path instead of calling the node module, you must remove `./` from the import sentence and use just `react-router-dom` instead.